# How to solve $e^z=2\sqrt3 - 2i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have been working with this equation for a long time now, and I just can't figure it out.

> Solve the following equation.
>   $$e^z=2\sqrt3 - 2i.$$

There should be three solutions that have a positive imaginary part. I hope some of you, can help me. Thank you :-)

Comment: Write the right side as $e^w$ for some $w\in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=x+yi$, then $e^z=e^x\bigl(\cos y+i\sin y\bigr)$. So$$e^z=2\sqrt3-2i=4\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2-\frac12i\right)\iff e^x=4\wedge\cos y=\frac{\sqrt3}2\wedge\sin y=-\frac12.$$So, take $x=\log4$, and $y=-\frac\pi6+2k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$).

Comment: My edit was for style. I thought the first line didn't need so many brackets......+1

Comment: So to get the three solutions with positive imaginary parts - should I then "just" put in some random constants instead of k?

Example: 
log(4)-Pi/6 +2·7·Pi

Comment: @Caroline The example that you provided is *not* a solution. But, yes, you should choose $k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $y>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=x+yi$, where $\{x,y\}\subset\mathbb R$.

Thus, $$e^x(\cos{y}+i\sin{y})=2\sqrt3-2i,$$
which gives
$$e^x\cos{y}=2\sqrt3$$ and
$$e^x\sin{y}=-2.$$

Thus, $$e^{2x}=(2\sqrt3)^2+(-2)^2,$$
which gives $$e^{2x}=16$$ or
$$x=2\ln2.$$
Hence, $\cos{y}=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and $\sin{y}=-\frac{1}{2}$, which gives 
$$y=\frac{11\pi}{6}+2\pi k,$$
where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Id est, we got the answer:
$$\left\{2\ln2+\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}+2\pi k\right)i|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}.$$
If you wish three solutions with positive imaginary part then we obtain for example:
$$\left\{2\ln2+\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}+2\pi k\right)i|k\in\{0,1,2\}\right\}.$$

Comment: Use radians when computing the arguments of complex numbers. That is, $330^\circ=\frac{11\pi}6$.